# Validating user input using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm trying to validate what a user enters into a texbox on the client-side, using javascript. I have also added a span close to my input tag like so,

```
<div>
                        <label for="fname">First Name*</label>                      
                        <input id="fname" name="fname" maxlength="30" type="text" /><span style="display:none;" id="fnameerror" name="fnameerror">*Please enter your firstname</span>
    </div>
```

Here's the javascript code snippet validating the input,

```
if(document.getElementById('fname').value.length==0){
            msg='Please enter your first name';
            document.getElementById('fnameerror').style.display='inline';
            document.getElementById('fnameerror').style.color='red';
            valid=false;
        }
```

What I want to achieve now is,
1) The textbox with the error should gain focus.
2) After the error message is displayed and the user enters a valid data, the error message should disappear.

How do I achieve this. I'm fairly new to javascript. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your JS code:

```
document.getElementById('fname').onkeyup = function() {
if(document.getElementById('fname').value.length==0){
            msg='Please enter your first name';
            document.getElementById('fnameerror').style.display='inline';
            document.getElementById('fnameerror').style.color='red';
            valid=false;
            document.getElementById('fname').focus();
        } else {
            valid=true;
            document.getElementById('fnameerror').style.display='none';
        }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chris97ong/6Tu3D/1/).

Comment: Thanks @chris970ng! this works without the `document.getElementById('fname').onkeyup = function()` part. Please can you explain what that part is doing so i can know how to add it to my code. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: So basically the `document.getElementById('fname').onkeyup` will get the following JS code to run once anything is in the input text is modified. Then `document.getElementById('fname').focus();` will get the input text to focus once the error is displayed. The `else` statement and whatever script that follows will get the element with ID `fnameerror` to hide. Hope my explanation helped.

Comment: okay, I tried adding that to my code, on clicking the submit button i didn't get any error for the input field but when i entered text and removed the text the error comes up. What is wrong please? @chris97ong

Comment: Set the ID of the submit button to `submitBtn`.
JS:
`document.getElementById('submitBtn').onclick = function() {
if(document.getElementById('fname').value.length==0){
            msg='Please enter your first name';
            document.getElementById('fnameerror').style.display='inline';
            document.getElementById('fnameerror').style.color='red';
            valid=false;
            document.getElementById('fname').focus();
        } else {
            valid=true;document.getElementById('fnameerror').style.display='none';
        }
}`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chris97ong/6Tu3D/2/)

Comment: Sry had to squeeze everything into one comment

Comment: Thanks a lot! Although the message isn't displayed via javascript now but the span, it works pretty well.Thank you. @chris97ong

Comment: @seun np. Anyway what do you mean by "isn't displayed via javascript"? It IS javascript.

Comment: I mean, the javascript alert message isn't displayed just the message set using the span. @chris97ong.

Comment: sorry to bother you again @chris97ong, I actually have two divs in my form and they contain different forms(i.e login and register forms).  I got the javascript working for the register div but it's not working for the login div. Both divs are on the same form. Please help!

Comment: @seun Could u give me a fiddle? Thx.

Comment: @seun Sorry I'm not very free now, but maybe u have to return false in the validate function. And do not put the ...`.onkeyup` in the validate function. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

If you've read about HTML5, it allows you to add form validation as attribute fields directly instead of having to write code for it. It also presents things neatly. Have a look. This might help: 
http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use [Jquery validator](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/). Of course you need to include jquery,and jquery plugin, but you do not need time to write validation from the scratch only to implement what exist.